# como saber si hay conexion o no con download manager en android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

Tengo la url para conectarme pero necesito verificar saber de que manera yo puedo decir cuando hay conexion o no a traves de un toast.Saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: Sería de gran ayuda que publicarás tu código para que podamos ayudarte

Answer (score 2):

Puedes comprobar el estado de conexión usando el `ConnectivityManager`:

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
    (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo infoRed = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean conectado = infoRed.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Para discriminar entre Wifi o conexión de datos puedes consultar:

```
int tipo = activeNetwork.getType();
switch(tipo){
    case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI:
        // caso wifi
        break;
    case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE:
        // caso telefono datos moviles
        break;
}
```

Más tipos de encuentras en la documentación de [`ConnectivityManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html).

Existe documentación sobre el tema en español en [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html).

Luego creas un `Toast` o un `Snackbar`con tu información:

```
int conectadoEstado = (conectado) ? R.string.connectado : R.string.no_conectado;
Snackbar.make(view, connectadoEstado, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();


int conectadoEstado = (conectado) ? R.string.connectado : R.string.no_conectado;
Toast.makeText(context, conectadoEstado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

También puedes registrar un `BroadcastReceiver` escuchando por "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE", y usar el `ConnectivityManager`para determinar el estado exacto de conectividad.